# как получить длступ к xaml из своего класса?

Tags: c#, uwp

Как получить доступ элементам MainPage.xaml из созданного мной класса?

Comment: Что вы имеете в виду под `получить доступ элементам MainPage.xaml из созданного мной класса?`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Чтобы получить доступ к элементам формы в своем классе необходимо передать ссылку на объект формы или на нужный контрол в созданный вами класс. Вот пример:

1) Создаем класс, поле которого хранит ссылку на вашу форму:

```
public class Class1
{
    private readonly MainWindow _form;

    public Class1(MainWindow form)
    {
        _form = form;
        _form.LabelTest.Content = "Тест";
    }
}
```

Класс получает ссылку на объект вашей формы в конструкторе и изменяет текст лейбла, который присутствует в форме, на "Тест".

2) Создаем экземпляр вашего класса, передав ссылку на класс вашей формы в конструкторе. Например это можно сделать в конструкторе класса формы:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        var c = new Class1(this);
    }
}
```

XAML формы:

```
    <Window x:Class="WpfApp2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp2"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Label Name="LabelTest" Content="Label" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="220,129,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если вам не нужно иметь прямой доступ к контролам формы, а нужно выводить/получать данные с нее, лучше используйте [паттерн MVVM](https://metanit.com/sharp/wpf/22.1.php)